# How to put YADCF filters in first row in the table

Tags: datatables, yadcf

I want to put YADCF filters as the first row in the table. Is there a config option for that? Currently, I have it as a part of header row.

I am able to put the filter in footer and use display:table-header-group to put it in the first row. However, this feature stops working when I use "scrollX": true to allow horizontal scrolling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the [filters_tr_index](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf/blob/b2cffd555b0fb8180c58600b49985e39ed335916/dist/jquery.dataTables.yadcf.js#L323)

As to integration with vertical scrolling, I'm not sure if it works properly (in the past there was no option to integrate with that feature)

> - filters_tr_index -
>                 Required:           false
>                 Type:               integer
>                 Default value:      undefined
>                 Description:        Allow to control the index of the  inside the thead of the table, e.g when one  is used for headers/sort and
>                                     another  is used for filters

Comment: It worked. Btw, this is a great plugin. Thanks for saving a lot of time for a lot of people.